# Generic List initialization in java

Tags: java, list, object, generics, arraylist

I have a problem with the initialization of a List . The Class of the Items isn't known at compile time - they could be int, float, string or custom classes.

So I tried this:

```
public class Sensordevice {
    private List<?> valueList;

    public void setValueList(List<?> valueList) {
        this.valueList = valueList;
    }   

    public void addValue(Object value) {
        if(valueList == null){
            valueList = getList(value.getClass());
        }
        valueList.add(value);
    }

    private <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

But I get this Error at valueList.add(value) in the addValue Methode:

> The method add(capture#4-of ?) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

---

Update

Thanks a lot for your replies. This solution works for my.

```
public class Sensordevice<T> {
    private List<T> valueList;

    public void setValueList(List<T> valueList) {
        this.valueList = valueList;
    }   

    public void addValue(T value) {
        if(valueList == null){
            valueList = new ArrayList<T>();
        }
        valueList.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no point creating a `List<T>` if it's declared as `List<?>`.

Comment: Why not just use a `List<Object>`?

Comment: I would rather advice you to create class `Sensordevice<T>`

Comment: Use `List<Object>`, or, given you will have something to do with the values, is there no common behaviour that could be design by an interface, (e.g. `Sensorable`), and just simply use this in `List<Sensorable>` and so on? I don't see the case for wildcard here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  And by "works" I mean I don't get any errors.  It doesn't seem to provide any functionality since there isn't any way to get the list of objects from the `Sensordevice` since `getList` just returns a new, empty list, but that's the code you gave.  I think the core of the error is having `addValue` take `Object` instead of `T`.

```
public class Sensordevice {
    private List valueList;

    public <T> void setValueList(List<T> valueList) {
        this.valueList = valueList;
    }

    public <T> void addValue(T value) {
        if(valueList == null){
            valueList = getList(value.getClass());
        }
        valueList.add(value);
    }

    private <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sensordevice sd = new Sensordevice();
    sd.addValue(new Object());
    sd.addValue(new Integer(3));
    sd.addValue("");
    sd.addValue(new Sensordevice());

    System.out.println(sd.getList(Sensordevice.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you don't know particular type would you class use, make your class generic:

```
public class Sensordevice<T> { 

    private List<T> valueList;

    public void setValueList(List<T> valueList) {
        this.valueList = valueList;
    }   

    public void addValue(T value) {
        if(valueList == null){
            valueList = getList(value.getClass());
        }
        valueList.add(value);
    }

    private List<T> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that he *really* wants to deal with lists of different types, where the type does not vary from program to program, but during the actual computation.

Comment: `getList(value.getClass());`   `private List<T> getList()`  is it working?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin then he needs `List<Object>` of just unparametrized `List`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the List type you can leave it without any type specification, just put: `private List valueList;`

Comment: Is this allowed *again*? I thought they deprecated it since at least 1.5? Maybe they re-introduced it for some reason, I'm not sure. Somewhere between 1.5 and 1.6 one certainly would get compiler warnings for that.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin it is not recommended, BTW it is still widely used in Java SE sources. Some libs are full of `@SupressWarnings("rawtypes")`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I assume those libs were grandfathered in. Are there libraries written in the past five years that use raw types?

Comment: Yeah, well... Maybe writing `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` once is indeed shorter than adding `<Object>` everywhere, in certain circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

Change the `valueList` to: private List valueList; and `getList()` to:

```
private <T> List<Object> getList(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
```

This fixes the error and it appears to work properly.
I tested it with strings, floats, and ints.

Comment: if `List<Object>` is always returned, what is purpose of `requiredType` at all?

Comment: It has to be list<Object> in order to satisfy 'private List<Object> valueList;'  You can keep your getList the way it is and make 'valueList = (List<Object>) getList(value.getClass());' in 'addValue', but this will give you a safety check warning.

Comment: If so, simple `getList()` is enough.